# "std::isdigit" is crashing for few extended ASCII Chars

Tags: c++, std

Due to some requirements, I need to walk through a string to see if any number exists in the string.

When I was trying below code, during my testing, the application crashed.. After careful observation, I noticed that the input string has special characters (extended ASCII Chars)..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string wordstr("tes¶¶"); //
    //int num  = unsigned char('¶'); // ASCII 182 (DEC)
    //int num1  = unsigned char('T'); // ASCII 84 (DEC)
    std::find_if(wordstr.begin(), wordstr.end(), ::isdigit) != wordstr.end();  
    return 0;
}
```

Why `std::isdigit` is crashing for extended ASCII values? (tried with few).

Is there any alternate standard function to find if the character is numeric, which wont crash if I have special chars in my input string?

*note: I am not supposed use C++11 and above, due to maintenance issues of this code base.*

Comment: Mesa no replicate! Yousa tell us compiler and version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 C++ complier

Comment: Ever wonder why C programmers cast the `char` parameter to `isXXX` to an `unsigned` type? `isXXX` requires an `int` argument, and a signed char with the sign bit lit will promote to a negative `int`.Sounds like your `isXXX` functions utilize a simple tabular lookup that doesn't play well with negative indexes.

Comment: I can't see how this could possibly "crash" - isdigit simply deals with integer values. What are the symptoms of the crash?

Comment: @WhozCraig all the character classification functions are supposed to behave sensibly for all possible inputs. You are not supposed to have to sanitise their parameters before calling them.

Comment: @Neil Crashed in crt\src\isctype.c

Comment: @Neil expression: (unsigned)(c+1) <= 256

Comment: @NeilButterworth that'd be sensible indeed. Unfortunately, all of these functions trigger UB if their input ["is not representable as `unsigned char` and is not equal to EOF"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Comment: -74 as an `unsigned int` is one stinking big number.  Way larger than 256.

Comment: @NeilButterworth:  What would "behave sensibly" mean on an implementation where char is signed?  If the function gets -1, it can't know whether it was a garbage value or an extended value equivalent to an unsigned char of 255.  If you always assume the latter, then you have to use something other than -1 for `EOF`, which undoubtedly breaks real code.  Since the standards explicitly call out UB for values that are neither EOF nor representable as unsigned char, the safest thing for an implementation to do is trust the caller to sanitize the arguments before the lossy implicit cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<ctype.h>` classification functions nominally accept an `int`, but the input value must be representable as an `unsigned char` or be the special value `EOF`. All other input result in undefined behavior. C11 §7.4p1:

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the
>   macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is
>   undefined.

C++ inherited this restriction. The solution is to cast any plain `char` argument to `unsigned char` (not `unsigned`!) before passing it to `::isdigit`, or to use the C++ locale-aware overload in `<locale>`.

Comment: But will not find_if in the OP's code be examining chars not ints?

Comment: yes......... now I have to go with a functor based on above suggestion..

Comment: Working after writing below functor... took a while to build. struct FindNumber
{
 bool operator() ( char schar ) const
 {
  int num = unsigned char(schar);
  return ::isdigit(num);
 }
};

Comment: Just curious, why std library do not have a function to handle this situation?

Comment: @katamarayudu you can just `std::find_if(wordstr.begin(), wordstr.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isdigit(c); })` :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar crash for `std::isspace()` when receiving email texts in our server code. And while searching internet, I stumbled upon this post. It seems that for all the `<cctype>` methods, one has to typecast to `unsigned char`.

Found a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) as below:

> Like all other functions from , the **behavior** of `std::isdigit` (`std::isxxx`) is **undefined** if the argument's value is neither representable as unsigned char nor equal to `EOF`. To use these functions safely with plain chars (or signed chars), the argument should first be converted to unsigned char:
> `bool my_isdigit(char ch) {return std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));}`